# Restler - How to pass a variable to a subclass

Tags: php, api, rest

I want to pass Restler::production_mode to one of my class methods, how can I do that from within the method?

```php
class Say {

    function get() {
        if (Restler::production_mode) { return 1; }
        else { return 0; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to accomplish with it, and where the method is. Is it in the same class?

Comment: the method is protected. Restler is the parent class I believe.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve? if production_mode is a variable, it should be public and static, so you can use Restler::$production_mode anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As of Restler 2.0 `$production_mode` is a protected property of Restler, so there is no easy way to access it. I suggest the following instead

In your index.php define PRODUCTION_MODE and use that to set production mode in Restler as shown below

```
define('PRODUCTION_MODE', FALSE); //or TRUE
spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload');
$r = new Restler(PRODUCTION_MODE);
$r->addAPIClass('Say');
$r->handle();
```

Then you can easily read the value from any class

```
class Say {

    function get() {
        if (PRODUCTION_MODE) { return 1; }
        else { return 0; }
    }

}
```